# How do I prevent a CSS transition from affecting my other icons on my page?

Tags: html, css

In advance, thank you for your time to look at this for me. I'm sort of new to making websites; I know the basics, and some advanced stuff. I'm working on my portfolio page, and I'm using icons for navigation. I have them all inside a div, and I have them all placed at relative positioning so i can keep them in the div. My problem came when I added a CSS transition to the icons to make them enlarge on hover, and when I do mouse over them the icon pushed the others down. I know I can use absolute positioning and this won't happen, but I'd prefer not to. Any tips?

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
    <div id="container_1">
<img class="icon" id="abouticon" src="assets/icons/abouticon.fw.png" width="80"      height="80">
<br>
<img class="icon" id="portfolioicon" src="assets/icons/portfolioicon.fw.png" width="80" height="80">
<br>
<img class="icon" id="facebookicon" src="assets/icons/facebookicon.fw.png" width="80" height="80">
<br>
<img class="icon" id="contacticon" src="assets/icons/emailicon.fw.png"  width="80" height="80">
```

And my CSS:

```
        #container_1    {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 25%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.icon   {
    transition: .2s ease;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.icon:hover {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    transition: .3s ease;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}



#abouticon  {
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#portfolioicon  {
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#facebookicon   {
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#contacticon    {
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are changing width, height, padding or margin of a relatively positioned block element, you are basically changing the properties of the box, which will inevitably result in repositioning of other elements in the flow.

I would use a transform instead:

```
.icon:hover {
    transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
    -o-transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
}
```

This will scale out the icon at +25% without affecting any of its box properties.

Please note: In order for this to work the way you want it to, you must remove all the changes to width, height, margin or padding from your `.icon:hover` declaration.

Also note: you do not need to re-apply the desired transition in your `:hover` declaration. It is enough to declare it in the base state (in your declaration of `.icon`, that is).